# How to split the text using selenium webdriver?

Tags: java, regex

I have text  like this **Hi Guys "Good Morning"**

I want to split the between of quotes text i.e Good Morning, so please help me out

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Unclear!!! what do you want actually as expected output??

Comment: I believe a good option would be a regex with three groups, one matching a quote, one matching anything and one matching a quote. If you can find something matching the regex in your string, the middle group will `Good Morning` (or whatever it says between the quotes).

Comment: i have to devide "Good Morning" text from whole text,
what Regex we have to use please help me out

Comment: your question title makes no sense.  selenium webdriver is for driving browsers.  it contains no facilities for splitting text.  This is a standard Java question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
...
String text = " Hi Guys \"Good Morning\"";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\"(.+?)\"");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
matcher.find();
System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
```

Comment: its working , thanks mac